# How to redirect DNS request to a remote systemd-resolved?

Tags: linux-networking, nat, nftables

I was trying to make system-resolved as a remote DNS caching server (I know it is not intended to do so). I added the changed the net.ipv4.conf.br0.route_localnet to 1 and added the following nftable rules:

```
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority 100; policy accept;
        iif "br0" udp dport 53 counter packets 6 bytes 366 dnat to 127.0.0.53
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority -100; policy accept;
        ip saddr 127.0.0.53 oif "br0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 snat to 192.168.1.2
    }
}
```

The prerouting rule seems working as there are packets matching the rules.  However there is no packet out of the host, what is the problem?

How can I redirect DNS request from 192.168.1.0/24 to systemd-resolved hosted on 192.168.1.2's lo device with IP 127.0.0.53?

Answer (score 1):

`systemd-resolved` binds to the `lo` interface:

```
# ss -aunp src == 127.0.0.53 sport == 53
State  Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port 
UNCONN 0      0      127.0.0.53%lo:53         0.0.0.0:*     users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=44157,fd=17))
```

This limits available routes even once `net.ipv4.conf.br0.route_localnet=1` is applied to those set on the `lo` interface:

```
$ ip -4 route show table all dev lo
broadcast 127.0.0.0 table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
```

None will match.

The source address would need to be changed. While the rarely used `type nat hook input` chain type would allow to change the source address before the application received it, it's already too late: this happens after routing was done and packet is already dropped. So stateful NAT can't handle this case.

---

Instead a proxy could be used for this (after removing all the specific nat settings). Here's an example using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). `socat` not being a dedicated application, there are caveats especially for UDP.

- TCP handling (OP forgot that DNS uses TCP too)

  ```
  socat TCP4-LISTEN:53,bind=192.168.1.2,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:127.0.0.53:53
  ```

  Can't bind to `IN_ADDR_ANY` because 127.0.0.53:53 is already bound, so bind to OP's provided address (for the wrong reasons): 192.168.1.2. Beside this, it's quite simple.
- UDP handling

  ```
  socat -T 20 UDP4-LISTEN:53,bind=192.168.1.2,reuseaddr,fork UDP4:127.0.0.53:53
  ```

  The 20s timeout is here because `socat` can't be told to cease right after receiving the single UDP packet answer and would keep all the forked `socat` commands accumulating over time.

  While UDP doesn't have to bind to an address in this case, binding to an address using UDP avoids the caveat related to multi-homing and the need to use the [`IP_PKTINFO`](https://manpages.debian.org/ip.7) socket option.